# Lavarel, connection to RDS through SSH

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds

it is my first project with Lavarel.

I have firstly created my project in pure PHP and test it (it works fine):

```
<?php
$ssh_host = 'ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com';
$ssh_user = 'ec2-user';
$ssh_key = '/Users/User/Desktop/private_key.pem';

$local_port = 3306; 
$remote_host = 'db-name.some-code.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$remote_port = 3306; 
$db_user = 'admin';
$db_pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'db-name';

try {   
    $command = 'ssh -i ' . $ssh_key . ' -N -L ' . $local_port . ':' . $remote_host . ':' . $remote_port . ' ' . $ssh_user . '@' . $ssh_host;
    $pid = shell_exec(sprintf("%s > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!", $command));

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=$local_port;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";

    try {
        $stmt = $dbh->query($query);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($result);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Błąd zapytania: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $dbh = null;

    exec("kill $pid");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Then I have created new Laravel project.

1. I added the appropriate credential data to file **config/database.php** (same as above)
2. I added the appropriate data to file **.env**
3. I added

   Route::get('/get-user', [UserController::class, 'getUser']);

into **routes/api.php** (to test it with postman)

4. I created UserControler.php inside **app/Http/Controllers** where are my mysql queries

and finally created  RDSService.php inside **app/Http/Services**:

```
<?php
// app/Services/RDSService.php

namespace App\Services;

use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

use PDO;
use Exception;

class RDSService
{
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ssh_host = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.ssh_host');
        $this->ssh_user = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.ssh_user');
        $this->ssh_key = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.ssh_key');
        $this->ssh_port = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.ssh_port');

        $this->db_host = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.db_host');
        $this->db_port = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.db_port');
        $this->db_name = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.db_name');
        $this->db_user = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.db_user');
        $this->db_pass = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.db_pass');
    }

    public function executeQuery($query, $params = [])
    {
        try {

            $ssh = new SSH2($this->ssh_host, $this->ssh_port);
            if (!$ssh->login($this->ssh_user, RSA::loadPrivateKey(file_get_contents($this->ssh_key)))) {
                throw new Exception('SSH login Error.');
            }

            $tunnel = new Forward($ssh);
            if (!$tunnel->listen('127.0.0.1', $this->db_port, $this->db_host, $this->db_port)) {
                throw new Exception('SSH tunnel construct error.');
            }

            $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port={$this->db_port};dbname={$this->db_name}";
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);

            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            $ssh->disconnect();

            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

But Postman still returns -->  Error: SSH login Error.
any idea what I am doing wrong? any tips how to check what exactly is wrong

thanks!

Comment: Why are you literally doing an `SSH` connection instead of using a model with a connection to RDS or a literal `DB::table(...)->...` ? Why SSH instead of using Eloquent?

Comment: RDS is not accessible outside VPC and I want to test it on localhost

Comment: It does not matter if your EC2 is running inside the same VPC as the RDS (it should, else it is totally inaccessible), you "must" use the connection config and eloquent, because it is going to be hyper easy to use

Comment: RDS and EC2 are in the same VPC, but i am not able to connect to RDS from my local computer (an i can not change it) it works only via ssh

Comment: If the RDS is private, yeah, you will never be able to connect to it. But that is the idea, RDS is for production, why do you want to connect it to your local environment? You can create a new one, but public. You are using it wrongly, use a `connection` and Eloquent (either a model or `DB::table()->...`), then it makes no sense you are using Laravel, you are making hard in purpose. Do you know how to use the `Model::connection('name')->...`? Do you need help with it?

Comment: Thanks! Not yet, but I will try to figure it out. If you can give me some advice, I'll gladly take it

Comment: You should have already everything set. You need to add a new connection on the config file (`config/database.php`), and then, if you have a model or models, you can either define the default connection for those as `protected $connection = 'config name you used';` (read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#database-connections)) so it will use your connection name as the default, instead of the default one set on the connection config. Something else you can do is, on every line of code, change the connection using `Model::connection('name')->...` (query) or `DB::connection('name')`